# Create Screen template or add footer?

Tags: blackberry, layout, java-me

I want to add a bitmap bar in the end of a loginscreen, and on top of that bitmap bar, i want to place to buttons (ok and cancel). How do i do that? Should i add that bar to some kind of backgroung template

```
public class EcraTemplate extends MainScreen {
    private HorizontalFieldManager hm;
    private MyLabelField title;
    private BitmapField logotipo;

    public EcraTemplate (long style) {
        super(style);
        ....
        logotipo = new BitmapField...

        title = new LabelField
        hm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hm.add(logotipo);

        //fill screen
        this.add(hm);
```

How would i add that bitmap with the buttons on top of it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Manager.setBackground()` call to accomplish this.

```
HorizontalFieldManager hm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png"); //whatever your background image name is
hm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bmp);
```

After that you can just add your buttons like normal. If you find that your HFM isn't the correct size, you can modify this to be

```
final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");
HorizontalFieldManager hm = new HorizontalFieldManager(){
    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        super.sublayout(width, height);
        setExtent(Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), width), Math.min(bmp.getHeight(), height));
    }
};

hm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bmp);
```

so that it will be the dimensions of your background image.

Comment: It would also be nice to mention the `Field.setBackground(Background background)` is available in the BB API since 4.6.0. This may be important because there are still lots of devices on OS 4.5 on the market (i.e. Curve 83xx series). For OS 4.5 you'll have to draw the bg image manually by overriding `Field.paint(Graphics graphics)`.

Comment: Excellent point. Your target OS definitely makes a difference as to how you accomplish this.